# If $f$ is analytic in a disk $|z|<R$ then so is $g(z)=\overline{f(\bar z)}$ in the disk

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

How to prove that if $f$ is analytic in a disk $|z|<R$ then $g(z)=\overline{f(\overline z)}$ is also analytic in the disk and also $f=g$ iff $f$ is real valued in $(-R,R)$

Comment: By taylor expansion.

Comment: Try using `\overline` instead of `\bar`. It comes out better, generally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As $f(z)$ is analytic there is a power series for $f$
$$f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k z^k $$ 
We know 
$$g(z)=\overline{\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k \overline{z}^k}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \overline{a_k} z^k$$
When $f$ is real valued on $(-R,R)$ all $a_k$ must be real and hence $\overline{a_k}=a_k$.

Comment: **Remark**: Cauchy-Hadamard tells us that the radius of convergence doesn’t change when complex-conjugating the coefficients of the taylor expansion.

**Question**: Of course, you have $f = g ⇔ ∀k∈ℕ: a_k = \overline{a_k}$. This directly shows $f = g ⇒ f(-R,R) ⊂ ℝ$. To show $ f(-R,R) ⊂ ℝ ⇒ f = g$, don’t you still need something like:
$$∀k ∈ ℕ:\quad a_k = \tfrac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!},\; \text{which is real, because}\; f^{(k)}(-R,R) ⊂ ℝ,$$
where the latter statement is proven inductively by looking at difference quotients?

Comment: oh i should have mentioned this one, you are totally right that one comes short in my proof

Answer (score 0):

Hint: CR Equation:$f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ is analytic so $u_x=v_y, v_x=-u_y$ now $g(z)=\overline{f(\bar{z})}=u(x,y)-iv(x,-y)$, $u_x=v_y$ and $v_x=-u_y$